# Manipulate map using different ways?

Tags: map-matching

I am hoping to find an elegant way of sorting a map by value first and then by the key.

For example:

B | 50

A | 50

C | 50

E | 10

D | 100

F | 99

I have the following code:

```
// Making the map into a list first
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> sortingList = new LinkedList<>(processMap.entrySet()); 

// Create a comparator that would compare the values of the map
Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> c = Comparator.comparingInt(Map -> Map.getValue());

// Sort the list in descending order
sortingList.sort(c.reversed());
```

I don't need the result to be map again, so this is sufficient, however, my result is:

D | 100

F | 99

B | 50

A | 50

C | 50

E | 10

I would like to sort not just by value, but also by the key, so the result becomes:

D | 100

F | 99

A | 50

B | 50

C | 50

E | 10

I had researched some possible solutions, but the problem is, my values need to be in descending, but my key has to be ascending...

Hoping if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> c = Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry<String, Integer>::getValue)
                                                     .reversed()
                                                     .thenComparing(Map.Entry::getKey);
```